# MediaMetadataRetriever.java on android unpublished API through Reflection

Tags: android, api, media

I'm interested in accessing this class:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.java

It is android unpublished API but is it a problem if I access it through reflection or it could lead to issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it but there's no guarantee it will be in the next Android version. Unless you take steps to handle this, it could all end very badly.

Comment: there is no guarantee means it might not be in the next Android version but it will still remain in all the current versions i.e. android 1.5, 1.6 or 2.0 won't be changed ?

Comment: It means there is no guarantee, in any way.  Device manufacturers are free to modify non-SDK code in any way they see fit, so the situation can be different on every different device that gets released.